# Can reptiles digest grains?

Tags: digestive-system, diet, reptile, digestion, herpetology

As a caretaker of a turtle, I sometimes struggle understanding the logic behind the inclusion of corn, soybean, and wheat meals in reptile food, such ingredients seem truly aberrant from what a reptile would naturally be exposed to. Nevertheless I am aware of the biological and chemical similarity between most organisms, so I wonder whether that will help reptiles, especially omnivores with an eclectic digestive ability, to digest these compounds.

I'm looking for legitimate studies on reptile digestibility; anecdotal experience or advice is supplementary if present.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a yes / no question. Many tortoise eat plants (veggies and fruits) while some turtles eat fish too. Snakes are basically predators and do not dwell on plants neither do most of the lizards. I think if a reptile is capable of digesting plant food in general, then it should be able to digest preprocessed grains as well.

Edit:  As for whole intact grains I'm unsure, as canadianer pointed out in comments section, intact grains are hard(er) to digest. /end of edit/
I found [this](http://jn.nutrition.org/content/120/7/775.long) article where scientist fed alligators with a mixed diet in various setup. The diet included corn too and the 'gators responded well in terms that they could use carbon-hydrates.

> Recently, we (3) have demonstrated that hatchling alligators benefit from and apparently do utilize some dietary carbohydrate.

Comment: Don't make the assumption that being able to digest some plant material means that the organism can digest all plant material. Whole grain is notoriously hard to digest for many animals.

Comment: Yes that is true, but the OP asked about wheat in reptile food which I assume is preprocessed and as such can be digested. Nevertheless you're absolutely right in your comment, I did not express exactly what I meant to write / say. My bad, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Ah yes, you make a good point. The original question did in fact specify wheat meal, meaning it has been processed.